# Issue with Flask-Marshmallow exposing DB contents via API

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I am developing a API which will return entries from a Database. I am using Flask-SQLAlchemy, Flask-Marshmallow, Flask-Admin and Docker to package it all up.

In one file Packages.py I have the following code regarding the database. The class PckagesSchema is the class I've added when trying to get Flash-Marshmallow working.

```
class Packages(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    trackingnumber = db.Column(db.String(15))
    email = db.Column(db.String(80))
    localid = db.Column(db.String(80))

class PackagesSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Packages
```

The in the main file I have the following snippets of code

```
from app.models import Packages, PackagesSchema
packages_schema = PackagesSchema()
db.create_all()
```

and then further down the part which will deal with API GET Requests.

```
@app.route('/packages', methods=['GET'])
def get_packages():
    result = packages_schema.dump(Packages).data
    return jsonify(result)
```

at the moment this returns:

```
{
  "email": "Packages.email", 
  "localid": "Packages.localid", 
  "trackingnumber": "Packages.trackingnumber"
}
```

However, there is definitely something in the database as the Flask-Admin app displays its.

This is my first day working with Flask-Marshmallow so I am not that experienced at all and would appreciate any help. I have read
https://flask-marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
but still stuck.

Comment: I think this part: result = `packages_schema.dump(Packages).data` needs to be a query in the parenthesis. So maybe something like
`packages_schema.dump(Packages.query.all()).data`.

Comment: BTW. Convention is for table names to be singular. So you might wast to change the class name in your model from Packages to Package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just brushed up a little on marshmallow:

```
@app.route('/packages', methods=['GET'])
def get_packages():
    packages = Packages.query.all()
    result = packages_schema.dump(packages).data
    return jsonify(result)
```

Should give you everything in there.  If you are returning many records, you need to add `packages_schema = PackagesSchema(many=True)`.

Also, not sure what version of flask you are running... but pre the latest release, I dont think jsonify would work here since you could not call it on a list.  Juts a heads up.

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice. I have got it working now using your updated code. It turned out `packages_schema = PackagesSchema(many=True)` was very important! I'll change the table names too. Thanks again.